# Encountering "cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, response, formidable

Having some weird errors with my nodejs server which I previously was't encountering. I get the error: 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" 
I am using formidable to process any formdata from my html page. Tried a lot of things to fix it, and looked online to people with similar problems but without any results. This is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var formidable = require("formidable");
var util = require('util');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;


var ram;
var disk;
var cpu;
var port = 80;
var ip = "172.19.0.1";

//als de user request doet naar form forward dan naar displayForom, else naar processallfieldsoftheForm om 
//invoer van de gebruiker te verwerken

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get') {
        displayForm(res);

    } else if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        processAllFieldsOfTheForm(req, res);
    }
});

//geef de html form weer 
function displayForm(res) {
    fs.readFile('form.html', function (err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'content-length' : data.length
        //error is here
        });
    res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
}


//functie om invoer van de gebruiker te verwerken serverside en als variabele op te slaan.
function processAllFieldsOfTheForm(req, res)  { 
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) 
{
    ram = (fields.mem)
    disk = (fields.dsk)
    cpu = (fields.cpu);
}
        );
            }


//exec('cat /home/js/text123', function(err, stdout, stderr){
//console.log(stdout);
//});


//serverside logs om te illistreren waar de server naar luistert, en waar hij luistert
server.listen(port, ip);
console.log("server lisening on " + port + " adress: " + ip);
```

Comment: Check the content of `err`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that the result of `fs.readFile('form.html'...` is not returning data.

Make sure that your `form.html` file is in the folder that you are running this code, otherwise, you will have to specify more of the path to the file.

You can also make use of the `err` variable passed into the callback to get better error checking. Try adding:

```
function displayForm(res) {
    fs.readFile('form.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err != null) {
           throw err;
           // OR
           console.log(err);
           // OR
           // Code to handle errors
           return; // If you don't throw
        } 

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'content-length' : data.length
        });
    res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is where you are having this problem:

```
function displayForm(res) {
    fs.readFile('form.html', function (err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'content-length' : data.length  // here, data is undefined due to some unexpected reason
        });
    res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
}
```

It's better to make some validations before accessing property of any object in JS. Try to find out the value of `data` before using it as `data.length`, somewhat like this:

```
function displayForm(res) {
    fs.readFile('form.html', function (err, data) {
        if ( (data != undefined || data != null) && (data.length > 0) ) {
           res.writeHead(200, {
              'Content-Type': 'text/html',
              'content-length' : data.length  // now data will always have some value
           });

           res.write(data);
           res.end();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing err to your callback function for readFile, you should check if err is not undefined, its possible there was some error with your readFile call.